# Search in laravel 5 with AppService Provider

Tags: php, laravel, search

In my template my search box is in the header and I need to make my function from `AppServiceProvider` so I can have access to it from all views.

My problem is that I don't know how to do it!

Here is my logic:

`Product` has `subcategory` and `subcategory` has `category` so i'm not get any `category_id` in my products instead i get `subcategory_id` in my products table.

#### What I want to do is:

**Show *category* names in dropdown BUT search in *subcategories* of that category.**

here is my form image:
[image: image one]

> Explain:

I have category `laptop` and it has subcategory `hp` `lg` `asus` which i have products in them. I want search `title xxxx` in category `laptop` and it look into those subcategories which are `hp, lg, asus`

So far I have this code in my `AppServiceProvider` but not sure about it

```
View::composer('frontend.index', function ($view) {

          $searchTitle = request('title');

          $subcategories = null;

          $subcategories = Subcategory::when($searchTitle, function ($query) use ($searchTitle) {
            return $query->where('title', 'like', "%{$searchTitle}%");
          })
          ->paginate(10)
          ->appends(request()->query());


        $view->with('subcategories', $subcategories);

      });
```

And this is my form:

```
<form class="search" action="">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">
                                                    <input type="text" name="q" class="search_box" placeholder="Enter your keyword ..." value="">
                                                    <div class="collections-selector">
                                                        <select class="single-option-selector" data-option="collection-option" id="collection-option" name="collection">
                                                            @foreach($subcategories as $search)
                                                            <option value="{{$search->id}}">{{$search->title}}</option>
                                                            @endforeach
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button class="search_submit" type="submit">
                                                        <svg aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" class="icon icon-search" viewBox="0 0 37 40"><path d="M35.6 36l-9.8-9.8c4.1-5.4 3.6-13.2-1.3-18.1-5.4-5.4-14.2-5.4-19.7 0-5.4 5.4-5.4 14.2 0 19.7 2.6 2.6 6.1 4.1 9.8 4.1 3 0 5.9-1 8.3-2.8l9.8 9.8c.4.4.9.6 1.4.6s1-.2 1.4-.6c.9-.9.9-2.1.1-2.9zm-20.9-8.2c-2.6 0-5.1-1-7-2.9-3.9-3.9-3.9-10.1 0-14C9.6 9 12.2 8 14.7 8s5.1 1 7 2.9c3.9 3.9 3.9 10.1 0 14-1.9 1.9-4.4 2.9-7 2.9z"></path></svg>
                                                    </button>
                                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the path: `project\app\Providers` there is a file `AppServiceProvider.php` having a method like:

```
public function boot()
{

}
```

In this `boot` method, put your logic and share what ever data you want to share on all views like:

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

now this `key` is available on all views no matter whether it is called from which controller.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: I bro that's what i did, my issue is to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I decided to use controller method instead of `AppServiceProvider` and get the route of `any` so user can use search box in any route.

```
Route::any()
```

Thanks for helps.